# External HDD not automounting at startup with udisksctl

Tags: mount, automount

Ubuntu 13.10 here. I have two external HDDs that are (almost) always plugged in. I want them to automout at startup, so I added two startup entries:

```
udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/disk/by-uuid/DISK1_UUID_HERE
```

and same for HDD2.

Now they almost always mount, almost. When they dont, running any udisksctl command will mount them. For example, even running only `udisksctl dump` mounts the two drives correctly.

Do you have any idea about why sometimes they don't automount properly at startup?

Thanks a lot

Comment: This can be hardware issues. This is because sometimes the external hard disk takes too long time to respond. This is completely normal, there's nothing wrong with your hardware or software, it is just the nature of the hardware.

Comment: @user220402 :Oh well that's interesting.. But can't one use a workaround? Like "if the hard disk is alive mount it, otherwise try it again in 3 seconds" very roughly speaking?

Answer (score 0):

**Answering old questions...**

- Hold the <kbd>Super</kbd> key *(usually the same as the Windows key)* and hit <kbd>a</kbd>.
- Type `startup` in the text entry field.
  [image: Dash 'Startup']
- `Startup Applications` should show up - click on it
  *(or use the cursor keys to select it and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>)*
- `Startup Application Preferences` should show up - click <kbd>Add</kbd>
  [image]
- Fill in the upper and lower fields with any text you wish.
- The middle field specifies what to do, type in

```
/bin/bash -c '/bin/sleep 5 && /usr/bin/udisksctl mount -b /dev/disk/by-label/GreenWD_3TB'
```

... where `/dev/disk/by-label/GreenWD_3TB` may be anything(?) that:

```
find /dev/disk/* -type l -printf "/dev/%l\t%p\n" \
| sed -re 's,\.\./,,g' -ne '/\/dev\/[a-z]+[0-9]\t/ p'
```

... does display. *(The text is formatted so that you may copy it 'as is' into the terminal)*
**I'd recommend to NOT use anything from the first column though - especially with removable devices as USB-sticks and/or drives.**